# How to activate multiple IN-APP PRODUCTS in google play developer console?

Tags: android, google-play, in-app-billing

Currently it's possible to activate manualy only one in-app product per click.

I can't find a way to select several in-app products and activate them in one step. 
Also there is no field like STATUS="active|inactive" in CVS file, when I want to import multiple in-app products.

So is batch activation of in-app products supported?

Comment: try changing the `Published State` column and insert pricing for the items.

Comment: according to  [Google Developer] docu (http://developer.android.com/google/play/billing/billing_admin.html#billing-catalog)
field Published State can have only these values:
**Publishing State
An item's publishing state can be Published or Unpublished . To be visible to a user during checkout, an item's publishing state must be set to Published and the item's application must be published on Google Play.**

Comment: I double checked and yes setting "Published State" to published helped. Thank you @petey